# Is there an R function to select one variable from each group (group_by()) from the dataframe?

Tags: r, dplyr, data-manipulation

I've a dataset where two variables interests me: `trial` and `truth`. Trial numbers the questions people were asked (in total 20). And truth stands for the correct answer for each question. I want to calculate the `log10()` of the truth for each question. I came up with this:

```
logT <- data %>% 
    group_by(trial) %>% 
    unique(truth, incomparables = F) %>% 
    summarize(log10(truth))
```

I'm not sure if it's the best idea to work with `unique()`, however in a small [dataframe](/questions/tagged/dataframe) the syntax works for me.

```
trial truth
1   1   34
2   1   34
3   2   321
4   2   321
5   3   78
6   3   78
```

But with the original data it keeps repeating all the rows, although they are exactly the same. So I end up with 1600 obs. instead of 20, which I'm aiming for. 
I used `select()` to work just with the relevant variables before running the argument, but it still doesn't work.

Where do I go wrong or is there a better way of doing it from scratch?

Comment: Are those values of `truth` the logs?

Answer (score 1):

Use `unique(mydata)` or `distinct(mydata)`.  Including the `log10` code we have:

```
mydata %>%
  distinct %>%
  mutate(truth = log10(truth))
```

### Note

The input, `mydata`, in reproducible form is assumed to be:

```
Lines <- "trial truth
1   1   34
2   1   34
3   2   321
4   2   321
5   3   78
6   3   78"
mydata <- read.table(text = Lines)
```

Comment: To compute the logs: `unique(data) %>% mutate(truth = log10(truth))`. No need to group by `trial`.

Answer (score 1):

A `dplyr` way could be

```
library(dplyr)

data %>%
  group_by(trial) %>%
  summarise(truth = first(log10(truth)))
```

Or, if the logarithms are already computed (unlikely),

```
data %>%
  group_by(trial) %>%
  summarise(truth = first(truth))
```

Answer (score 1):

With `dplyr`, we can also use `distinct`

```
library(dplyr)
distinct(data)
```